# Solution to a differential equation with various options

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to Differential Equations (first week), and am stuck with the following question:

What is the general solution of $$ydx+\left(\frac{e^x}{y}-1\right)dy=0~?$$

I tried the following logic:
$(\frac{e^x}{y}-1)dy=-ydx$, then integration both sides, which gives:
$-y+e^x\ln|y|=-yx+C$, and thus $-y+yx+e^x\ln|y|=C$. However, this does not figure amongst the options:

$1. ~~~~~\ln|x|+ye^y=C$

$2. ~~~~~\ln|y|-ye^{-x}=C$

$3. ~~~~~\ln|y|+ye^x=C$

$4. ~~~~~y \ln(y)-e^x=C$

Where is my mistake, and how do I proceed to the answer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve a DE with separation of variables, you need to do just that. Separate the variables, ie, have all terms with variable x on one side, all terms with y on other side, then integrate.

What you did is $\frac{(e^x - 1)}{y} dy = -y dx$ is wrong because you clearly have an $e^x$ term on left when you are integrating with respect to $dy$, and on the right you have a $y$ term when you are integrating with respect to $dx$.

Do some algebra, separate variables, then integrate.

Answer (score 1):

$$ydx+\left(\frac{e^x}{y}-1\right)dy=0\tag1$$which can be written in the form $$Mdx+Ndy=0\qquad\text{where}\quad M=y,~~N=\left(\frac{e^x}{y}-1\right)$$
Now $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=1,\qquad \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\frac{e^x}{y}$$
Since $~\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\ne \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}~$, so the given differential equation is not exact. Now to make it exact we have found the integrating factor. Here $$h(x)=\frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)=-1$$so the integrating factor is $$\text{I.F.}=~e^{\int h(x)~dx}=e^{-x}~$$
Multiplying equation $(1)$ by I.F. we have $$y~e^{-x}dx+e^{-x}~\left(\frac{e^x}{y}-1\right)dy=0\tag2$$Clearly, it is  an exact differential equation.

From equation $(2)$, $$y~e^{-x}dx-e^{-x}dy+\frac{dy}{y}=0$$integrating we have $$-e^{-x}~y+\log |y|=c\qquad\text{where $~c~$ is constant}~.$$

So the option $(2)$ is correct.